# About the term of law, and the interpretation

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> 1.Signing a form is little more than a formality.

I know the sentence can be changeable like the following below.

> 2.Signing a form is only a formality.

But can I change the first sentence into others like the followings below, and
Is the meaning also all the same?(with number 3,4)

> 3.Signing a form isn’t much more than a formality.

> 4.Signing a form isn’t much more than signing a form is a formality.

Lastly, I want to know the part of speech of the word “more” in all sentences above.

> 5.Signing a form isn't any more than signing a form is a formality.

what difference exists from 1,2,3 and 4 sentences compared with 5 sentence?

Comment: Repeating _signing a form_ makes (4) and (5) nonsense. I would expect '**a** formality' in the other versions.

Answer (score 1):

The following two of your example sentences are equivalent:

> 1.Signing a form is little more than a formality.
> 3.Signing a form isn’t much more than a formality.

"Not much more than" and "little more than" do the same thing - they indicate that signing the form is more than just a formality, but only a bit - in other words, signing the form has some real meaning beyond being a formality, but this real meaning is quite minimal. On the other hand:

> 2.Signing a form is only a formality.

This means that signing the form is a formality and has no real meaning or further function.

Examples 4 and 5 are impossible to understand.

Comment: @curthers thank you for the post. I know 4,5 are wrong because the ellipsis is obligatory in comparative.  by the way, my question is what part of speech the word "more" is in each sentence.

Comment: @bak1936 We only answer one question at a time on this site. Asking two questions can get your question [closed] until you remove the second question. So, if you want to know the part of speech of "more", please ask that in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement cruthers' fine answer:

Sentences 4 and 5 are impossible for anyone to understand.

The comparison is made with "*isn't much more than*". Here's the structure, with the two items being compared in bold:

4. **Signing a form** isn’t much more than **signing a form is a formality**.

The first part of the comparison is a *noun*: the act of signing a form. The second part of the comparison is a *clause*: an statement about signing forms. You cannot compare **an action** to a **statement**.

Sentence 5 has the same issue.

Comment: thank you for post. how do you know the second part of the comparison is the degree? in the sentence "signing form is little more than a formality", what does formality express in the sentence? is it a degree?

Comment: @bak1936 I've improved my answer about 4 and 5. Does that make it clearer?